# How can I stop my number of balls being added in my HTML canvas exponentially?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I currently have a code that when the user clicks on `addBall()`, a new ball is created on a canvas and they bounce around. However, when the user clicks this button more and more, the number of balls added is the same as the previous count should have been. It *should* only be adding one every time the button is clicked.

Imagine you click the button once, it will add one ball. Click it again, it adds two balls. Click it one more time, it adds 3 balls. This continues on in this way forever until my poor little Chromebook crashes.

**Question**: How can I make the number of balls being made per click be one forever?

```js
function lineMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').textContent += msg + '. ';
}

function groupMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').innerHTML += msg + '<br/>';
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 550;
const ballCount = document.querySelector('#ball-count');

const gravity = 0;
const wallLoss = 1;
let numBalls = 0;  // approx as will not add ball if space can not be found
const minBallSize = 13;
const maxBallSize = 20;
const velMin = 1;
const velMax = 5; 
const maxResolutionCycles = 100;

Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
Math.rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
Math.randI = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min | 0; // only for positive numbers 32bit signed int
Math.randItem = arr => arr[Math.random() * arr.length | 0]; // only for arrays with length < 2 ** 31 - 1
// contact points of two circles radius r1, r2 moving along two lines (a,e)-(b,f) and (c,g)-(d,h) [where (,) is coord (x,y)]
Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime = (a, e, b, f, c, g, d, h, r1, r2) => { // args (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, r1, r2)
    const A = a * a, B = b * b, C = c * c, D = d * d;
    const E = e * e, F = f * f, G = g * g, H = h * h;
    var R = (r1 + r2) ** 2;
    const AA = A + B + C + F + G + H + D + E + b * c + c * b + f * g + g * f + 2 * (a * d - a * b - a * c - b * d - c * d - e * f + e * h - e * g - f * h - g * h);
    const BB = 2 * (-A + a * b + 2 * a * c - a * d - c * b - C + c * d - E + e * f + 2 * e * g - e * h - g * f - G + g * h);
    const CC = A - 2 * a * c + C + E - 2 * e * g + G - R;
    return Math.quadRoots(AA, BB, CC);
}  

Math.quadRoots = (a, b, c) => { // find roots for quadratic
    if (Math.abs(a) < 1e-6) {
        return b != 0 ? [-c / b] : [] 
    }

    b /= a;
    var d = b * b - 4 * (c / a);

    if (d > 0) {
        d = d ** 0.5;
        return  [0.5 * (-b + d), 0.5 * (-b - d)]
    }

    return d === 0 ? [0.5 * -b] : [];
}

Math.interceptLineBallTime = (x, y, vx, vy, x1, y1, x2, y2, r) => {
    const xx = x2 - x1;
    const yy = y2 - y1;
    const d = vx * yy - vy * xx;

    if (d > 0) {  // only if moving towards the line
        const dd = r / (xx * xx + yy * yy) ** 0.5;
        const nx = xx * dd;
        const ny = yy * dd;
        return (xx * (y - (y1 + nx)) - yy * (x - (x1 - ny))) / d;
    }
}

const balls = [];
const lines = [];

function Line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
}

Line.prototype = {
    draw() {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
    },
    reverse() {
        const x = this.x1;
        const y = this.y1;
        this.x1 = this.x2;
        this.y1 = this.y2;
        this.x2 = x;
        this.y2 = y;
        return this;
    }
}
        
function Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r = 45, m = 4 / 3 * Math.PI * (r ** 3)) {
    this.r = r;
    this.m = m;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
}

Ball.prototype = {
    update() {
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;
        this.vy += gravity;
    },
    draw() {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.r, this.y);
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.TAU);
    },
    interceptLineTime(l, time) {
        const u = Math.interceptLineBallTime(this.x, this.y, this.vx, this.vy, l.x1, l.y1, l.x2, l.y2, this.r);

        if (u >= time && u <= 1) {
            return u;
        }
    },
    checkBallBallTime(t, minTime) {
        return t > minTime && t <= 1;
    },
    interceptBallTime(b, time) {
        const x = this.x - b.x;
        const y = this.y - b.y;
        const d = (x * x + y * y) ** 0.5;

        if (d > this.r + b.r) {
            const times = Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime(
                this.x, this.y, 
                this.x + this.vx, this.y + this.vy, 
                b.x, b.y,
                b.x + b.vx, b.y + b.vy, 
                this.r, b.r
            )

            if (times.length) {
                if (times.length === 1) {
                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                        return times[0]
                    }

                    return;
                }

                if (times[0] <= times[1]) {
                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                        return times[0]
                    }

                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) {
                        return times[1]
                    }

                    return
                }

                if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) { 
                    return times[1]
                }      

                if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                    return times[0]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    collideLine(l, time) {
        const x1 = l.x2 - l.x1;
        const y1 = l.y2 - l.y1;
        const d = (x1 * x1 + y1 * y1) ** 0.5;
        const nx = x1 / d;
        const ny = y1 / d;            
        const u = (this.vx  * nx + this.vy  * ny) * 2;
        this.x += this.vx * time;   
        this.y += this.vy * time;   
        this.vx = (nx * u - this.vx) * wallLoss;
        this.vy = (ny * u - this.vy) * wallLoss;
        this.x -= this.vx * time;
        this.y -= this.vy * time;
    },
    collide(b, time) {
        const a = this;
        const m1 = a.m;
        const m2 = b.m;
        const x = a.x - b.x
        const y = a.y - b.y  
        const d = (x * x + y * y);
        const u1 = (a.vx * x + a.vy * y) / d
        const u2 = (x * a.vy - y * a.vx ) / d
        const u3 = (b.vx * x + b.vy * y) / d
        const u4 = (x * b.vy - y * b.vx ) / d
        const mm = m1 + m2;
        const vu3 = (m1 - m2) / mm * u1 + (2 * m2) / mm * u3;
        const vu1 = (m2 - m1) / mm * u3 + (2 * m1) / mm * u1;
        a.x = a.x + a.vx * time;
        a.y = a.y + a.vy * time;
        b.x = b.x + b.vx * time;
        b.y = b.y + b.vy * time;
        b.vx = x * vu1 - y * u4;
        b.vy = y * vu1 + x * u4;
        a.vx = x * vu3 - y * u2;
        a.vy = y * vu3 + x * u2;
        a.x = a.x - a.vx * time;
        a.y = a.y - a.vy * time;
        b.x = b.x - b.vx * time;
        b.y = b.y - b.vy * time;
    },
    doesOverlap(ball) {
        const x = this.x - ball.x;
        const y = this.y - ball.y;
        return  (this.r + ball.r) > ((x * x + y * y) ** 0.5);  
    }       
}

function canAdd(ball) {
    for (const b of balls) {
        if (ball.doesOverlap(b)) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function create(bCount) {
    lines.push(new Line(-10, 10, ctx.canvas.width + 10, 5));
    lines.push((new Line(-10, ctx.canvas.height - 2, ctx.canvas.width + 10, ctx.canvas.height - 10)).reverse());
    lines.push((new Line(10, -10, 4, ctx.canvas.height + 10)).reverse());
    lines.push(new Line(ctx.canvas.width - 3, -10, ctx.canvas.width - 10, ctx.canvas.height + 10)); 

    while (bCount--) {
        let tries = 100;
        debugger

        while (tries--) {
            const dir = Math.rand(0, Math.TAU);
            const vel = Math.rand(velMin, velMax);
            const ball = new Ball(
                Math.rand(maxBallSize + 10, canvas.width - maxBallSize - 10), 
                Math.rand(maxBallSize + 10, canvas.height - maxBallSize - 10),
                Math.cos(dir) * vel,
                Math.sin(dir) * vel,
                Math.rand(minBallSize, maxBallSize),
            )

            if (canAdd(ball)) {
                balls.push(ball);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function resolveCollisions() {
    var minTime = 0, minObj, minBall, resolving = true, idx = 0, idx1, after = 0, e = 0;
        
    while (resolving && e++ < maxResolutionCycles) { // too main ball may create very lone resolution cycle. e limits this
        resolving = false;
        minObj = undefined;
        minBall = undefined;
        minTime = 1;
        idx = 0;

        for(const b of balls) {
            idx1 = idx + 1;
            while (idx1 < balls.length) {
                const b1 = balls[idx1++];
                const time = b.interceptBallTime(b1, after);

                if (time !== undefined) {
                    if (time <= minTime) {
                         minTime = time;
                        minObj = b1;
                        minBall = b;
                        resolving = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (const l of lines) {
                 const time = b.interceptLineTime(l, after);
                if (time !== undefined) {
                    if (time <= minTime) {
                        minTime = time;
                        minObj = l;
                        minBall = b;
                        resolving = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            idx++;
        }

        if (resolving) {
            if (minObj instanceof Ball) {
                minBall.collide(minObj, minTime);
            } else {
                minBall.collideLine(minObj, minTime);
            }

            after = minTime;
        }
    }
}

function mainLoop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    resolveCollisions();

    for (const b of balls) {
        b.update()
    }

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();

    for (const b of balls) {
        b.draw()
    }

    for (const l of lines) {
        l.draw()
    }

    ctx.stroke();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}    

function addBall() {
    numBalls++;
    ballCount.innerHTML = numBalls;
    create(numBalls);
}

mainLoop();
```

```css
#canvas {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 550px
}

#myConsole {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <title>Bouncy Balls</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="addBall()">Add Ball</button><br>
        <div>Ball Count: <span id="ball-count">0</span></div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <p id="myConsole">&gt;&nbsp;<span id="myMessage"></span></p>

        <script src="app2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `create` be called with `1`?

Comment: @ScottHunter Sorry, I don't quite understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a count of balls to the create method when you really only want to create one new ball.  For instance, on the second click, create will receive 2 as the bCount parameter and proceed to create two new balls.

Below is your code, the only modification I made is to set `bCount = 1;` as the very first line in create.  This will cause the method to create only ball instead of the count of balls passed in.

```js
function lineMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').textContent += msg + '. ';
}

function groupMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').innerHTML += msg + '<br/>';
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 550;
const ballCount = document.querySelector('#ball-count');

const gravity = 0;
const wallLoss = 1;
let numBalls = 0;  // approx as will not add ball if space can not be found
const minBallSize = 13;
const maxBallSize = 20;
const velMin = 1;
const velMax = 5; 
const maxResolutionCycles = 100;

Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
Math.rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
Math.randI = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min | 0; // only for positive numbers 32bit signed int
Math.randItem = arr => arr[Math.random() * arr.length | 0]; // only for arrays with length < 2 ** 31 - 1
// contact points of two circles radius r1, r2 moving along two lines (a,e)-(b,f) and (c,g)-(d,h) [where (,) is coord (x,y)]
Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime = (a, e, b, f, c, g, d, h, r1, r2) => { // args (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, r1, r2)
    const A = a * a, B = b * b, C = c * c, D = d * d;
    const E = e * e, F = f * f, G = g * g, H = h * h;
    var R = (r1 + r2) ** 2;
    const AA = A + B + C + F + G + H + D + E + b * c + c * b + f * g + g * f + 2 * (a * d - a * b - a * c - b * d - c * d - e * f + e * h - e * g - f * h - g * h);
    const BB = 2 * (-A + a * b + 2 * a * c - a * d - c * b - C + c * d - E + e * f + 2 * e * g - e * h - g * f - G + g * h);
    const CC = A - 2 * a * c + C + E - 2 * e * g + G - R;
    return Math.quadRoots(AA, BB, CC);
}  

Math.quadRoots = (a, b, c) => { // find roots for quadratic
    if (Math.abs(a) < 1e-6) {
        return b != 0 ? [-c / b] : [] 
    }

    b /= a;
    var d = b * b - 4 * (c / a);

    if (d > 0) {
        d = d ** 0.5;
        return  [0.5 * (-b + d), 0.5 * (-b - d)]
    }

    return d === 0 ? [0.5 * -b] : [];
}

Math.interceptLineBallTime = (x, y, vx, vy, x1, y1, x2, y2, r) => {
    const xx = x2 - x1;
    const yy = y2 - y1;
    const d = vx * yy - vy * xx;

    if (d > 0) {  // only if moving towards the line
        const dd = r / (xx * xx + yy * yy) ** 0.5;
        const nx = xx * dd;
        const ny = yy * dd;
        return (xx * (y - (y1 + nx)) - yy * (x - (x1 - ny))) / d;
    }
}

const balls = [];
const lines = [];

function Line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
}

Line.prototype = {
    draw() {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
    },
    reverse() {
        const x = this.x1;
        const y = this.y1;
        this.x1 = this.x2;
        this.y1 = this.y2;
        this.x2 = x;
        this.y2 = y;
        return this;
    }
}
        
function Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r = 45, m = 4 / 3 * Math.PI * (r ** 3)) {
    this.r = r;
    this.m = m;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
}

Ball.prototype = {
    update() {
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;
        this.vy += gravity;
    },
    draw() {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.r, this.y);
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.TAU);
    },
    interceptLineTime(l, time) {
        const u = Math.interceptLineBallTime(this.x, this.y, this.vx, this.vy, l.x1, l.y1, l.x2, l.y2, this.r);

        if (u >= time && u <= 1) {
            return u;
        }
    },
    checkBallBallTime(t, minTime) {
        return t > minTime && t <= 1;
    },
    interceptBallTime(b, time) {
        const x = this.x - b.x;
        const y = this.y - b.y;
        const d = (x * x + y * y) ** 0.5;

        if (d > this.r + b.r) {
            const times = Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime(
                this.x, this.y, 
                this.x + this.vx, this.y + this.vy, 
                b.x, b.y,
                b.x + b.vx, b.y + b.vy, 
                this.r, b.r
            )

            if (times.length) {
                if (times.length === 1) {
                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                        return times[0]
                    }

                    return;
                }

                if (times[0] <= times[1]) {
                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                        return times[0]
                    }

                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) {
                        return times[1]
                    }

                    return
                }

                if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) { 
                    return times[1]
                }      

                if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                    return times[0]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    collideLine(l, time) {
        const x1 = l.x2 - l.x1;
        const y1 = l.y2 - l.y1;
        const d = (x1 * x1 + y1 * y1) ** 0.5;
        const nx = x1 / d;
        const ny = y1 / d;            
        const u = (this.vx  * nx + this.vy  * ny) * 2;
        this.x += this.vx * time;   
        this.y += this.vy * time;   
        this.vx = (nx * u - this.vx) * wallLoss;
        this.vy = (ny * u - this.vy) * wallLoss;
        this.x -= this.vx * time;
        this.y -= this.vy * time;
    },
    collide(b, time) {
        const a = this;
        const m1 = a.m;
        const m2 = b.m;
        const x = a.x - b.x
        const y = a.y - b.y  
        const d = (x * x + y * y);
        const u1 = (a.vx * x + a.vy * y) / d
        const u2 = (x * a.vy - y * a.vx ) / d
        const u3 = (b.vx * x + b.vy * y) / d
        const u4 = (x * b.vy - y * b.vx ) / d
        const mm = m1 + m2;
        const vu3 = (m1 - m2) / mm * u1 + (2 * m2) / mm * u3;
        const vu1 = (m2 - m1) / mm * u3 + (2 * m1) / mm * u1;
        a.x = a.x + a.vx * time;
        a.y = a.y + a.vy * time;
        b.x = b.x + b.vx * time;
        b.y = b.y + b.vy * time;
        b.vx = x * vu1 - y * u4;
        b.vy = y * vu1 + x * u4;
        a.vx = x * vu3 - y * u2;
        a.vy = y * vu3 + x * u2;
        a.x = a.x - a.vx * time;
        a.y = a.y - a.vy * time;
        b.x = b.x - b.vx * time;
        b.y = b.y - b.vy * time;
    },
    doesOverlap(ball) {
        const x = this.x - ball.x;
        const y = this.y - ball.y;
        return  (this.r + ball.r) > ((x * x + y * y) ** 0.5);  
    }       
}

function canAdd(ball) {
    for (const b of balls) {
        if (ball.doesOverlap(b)) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function create(bCount) {
    bCount = 1;
    lines.push(new Line(-10, 10, ctx.canvas.width + 10, 5));
    lines.push((new Line(-10, ctx.canvas.height - 2, ctx.canvas.width + 10, ctx.canvas.height - 10)).reverse());
    lines.push((new Line(10, -10, 4, ctx.canvas.height + 10)).reverse());
    lines.push(new Line(ctx.canvas.width - 3, -10, ctx.canvas.width - 10, ctx.canvas.height + 10)); 

    while (bCount--) {
        let tries = 100;
        debugger

        while (tries--) {
            const dir = Math.rand(0, Math.TAU);
            const vel = Math.rand(velMin, velMax);
            const ball = new Ball(
                Math.rand(maxBallSize + 10, canvas.width - maxBallSize - 10), 
                Math.rand(maxBallSize + 10, canvas.height - maxBallSize - 10),
                Math.cos(dir) * vel,
                Math.sin(dir) * vel,
                Math.rand(minBallSize, maxBallSize),
            )

            if (canAdd(ball)) {
                balls.push(ball);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function resolveCollisions() {
    var minTime = 0, minObj, minBall, resolving = true, idx = 0, idx1, after = 0, e = 0;
        
    while (resolving && e++ < maxResolutionCycles) { // too main ball may create very lone resolution cycle. e limits this
        resolving = false;
        minObj = undefined;
        minBall = undefined;
        minTime = 1;
        idx = 0;

        for(const b of balls) {
            idx1 = idx + 1;
            while (idx1 < balls.length) {
                const b1 = balls[idx1++];
                const time = b.interceptBallTime(b1, after);

                if (time !== undefined) {
                    if (time <= minTime) {
                         minTime = time;
                        minObj = b1;
                        minBall = b;
                        resolving = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (const l of lines) {
                 const time = b.interceptLineTime(l, after);
                if (time !== undefined) {
                    if (time <= minTime) {
                        minTime = time;
                        minObj = l;
                        minBall = b;
                        resolving = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            idx++;
        }

        if (resolving) {
            if (minObj instanceof Ball) {
                minBall.collide(minObj, minTime);
            } else {
                minBall.collideLine(minObj, minTime);
            }

            after = minTime;
        }
    }
}

function mainLoop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    resolveCollisions();

    for (const b of balls) {
        b.update()
    }

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();

    for (const b of balls) {
        b.draw()
    }

    for (const l of lines) {
        l.draw()
    }

    ctx.stroke();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}    

function addBall() {
    numBalls++;
    ballCount.innerHTML = numBalls;
    create(numBalls);
}

mainLoop();
```

```css
#canvas {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 550px
}

#myConsole {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <title>Bouncy Balls</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="addBall()">Add Ball</button><br>
        <div>Ball Count: <span id="ball-count">0</span></div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <p id="myConsole">&gt;&nbsp;<span id="myMessage"></span></p>

        <script src="app2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it doesn't use the parameter, it shouldn't have the parameter at all. If it's just supposed to create one ball, there's no need for the loop.

Comment: @Barmar you are right but my goal was to show the source of the logical mistake and OP can take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `addBall`, the parameter of `create()` needs to be `1` rather than `numBalls`:

```
function addBall() {
    numBalls++;
    ballCount.innerHTML = numBalls;
    create(1);
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
function lineMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').textContent += msg + '. ';
}

function groupMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').innerHTML += msg + '<br/>';
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 550;
const ballCount = document.querySelector('#ball-count');

const gravity = 0;
const wallLoss = 1;
let numBalls = 0;  // approx as will not add ball if space can not be found
const minBallSize = 13;
const maxBallSize = 20;
const velMin = 1;
const velMax = 5; 
const maxResolutionCycles = 100;

Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
Math.rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
Math.randI = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min | 0; // only for positive numbers 32bit signed int
Math.randItem = arr => arr[Math.random() * arr.length | 0]; // only for arrays with length < 2 ** 31 - 1
// contact points of two circles radius r1, r2 moving along two lines (a,e)-(b,f) and (c,g)-(d,h) [where (,) is coord (x,y)]
Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime = (a, e, b, f, c, g, d, h, r1, r2) => { // args (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, r1, r2)
    const A = a * a, B = b * b, C = c * c, D = d * d;
    const E = e * e, F = f * f, G = g * g, H = h * h;
    var R = (r1 + r2) ** 2;
    const AA = A + B + C + F + G + H + D + E + b * c + c * b + f * g + g * f + 2 * (a * d - a * b - a * c - b * d - c * d - e * f + e * h - e * g - f * h - g * h);
    const BB = 2 * (-A + a * b + 2 * a * c - a * d - c * b - C + c * d - E + e * f + 2 * e * g - e * h - g * f - G + g * h);
    const CC = A - 2 * a * c + C + E - 2 * e * g + G - R;
    return Math.quadRoots(AA, BB, CC);
}  

Math.quadRoots = (a, b, c) => { // find roots for quadratic
    if (Math.abs(a) < 1e-6) {
        return b != 0 ? [-c / b] : [] 
    }

    b /= a;
    var d = b * b - 4 * (c / a);

    if (d > 0) {
        d = d ** 0.5;
        return  [0.5 * (-b + d), 0.5 * (-b - d)]
    }

    return d === 0 ? [0.5 * -b] : [];
}

Math.interceptLineBallTime = (x, y, vx, vy, x1, y1, x2, y2, r) => {
    const xx = x2 - x1;
    const yy = y2 - y1;
    const d = vx * yy - vy * xx;

    if (d > 0) {  // only if moving towards the line
        const dd = r / (xx * xx + yy * yy) ** 0.5;
        const nx = xx * dd;
        const ny = yy * dd;
        return (xx * (y - (y1 + nx)) - yy * (x - (x1 - ny))) / d;
    }
}

const balls = [];
const lines = [];

function Line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
}

Line.prototype = {
    draw() {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
    },
    reverse() {
        const x = this.x1;
        const y = this.y1;
        this.x1 = this.x2;
        this.y1 = this.y2;
        this.x2 = x;
        this.y2 = y;
        return this;
    }
}
        
function Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r = 45, m = 4 / 3 * Math.PI * (r ** 3)) {
    this.r = r;
    this.m = m;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
}

Ball.prototype = {
    update() {
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;
        this.vy += gravity;
    },
    draw() {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.r, this.y);
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.TAU);
    },
    interceptLineTime(l, time) {
        const u = Math.interceptLineBallTime(this.x, this.y, this.vx, this.vy, l.x1, l.y1, l.x2, l.y2, this.r);

        if (u >= time && u <= 1) {
            return u;
        }
    },
    checkBallBallTime(t, minTime) {
        return t > minTime && t <= 1;
    },
    interceptBallTime(b, time) {
        const x = this.x - b.x;
        const y = this.y - b.y;
        const d = (x * x + y * y) ** 0.5;

        if (d > this.r + b.r) {
            const times = Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime(
                this.x, this.y, 
                this.x + this.vx, this.y + this.vy, 
                b.x, b.y,
                b.x + b.vx, b.y + b.vy, 
                this.r, b.r
            )

            if (times.length) {
                if (times.length === 1) {
                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                        return times[0]
                    }

                    return;
                }

                if (times[0] <= times[1]) {
                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                        return times[0]
                    }

                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) {
                        return times[1]
                    }

                    return
                }

                if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) { 
                    return times[1]
                }      

                if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                    return times[0]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    collideLine(l, time) {
        const x1 = l.x2 - l.x1;
        const y1 = l.y2 - l.y1;
        const d = (x1 * x1 + y1 * y1) ** 0.5;
        const nx = x1 / d;
        const ny = y1 / d;            
        const u = (this.vx  * nx + this.vy  * ny) * 2;
        this.x += this.vx * time;   
        this.y += this.vy * time;   
        this.vx = (nx * u - this.vx) * wallLoss;
        this.vy = (ny * u - this.vy) * wallLoss;
        this.x -= this.vx * time;
        this.y -= this.vy * time;
    },
    collide(b, time) {
        const a = this;
        const m1 = a.m;
        const m2 = b.m;
        const x = a.x - b.x
        const y = a.y - b.y  
        const d = (x * x + y * y);
        const u1 = (a.vx * x + a.vy * y) / d
        const u2 = (x * a.vy - y * a.vx ) / d
        const u3 = (b.vx * x + b.vy * y) / d
        const u4 = (x * b.vy - y * b.vx ) / d
        const mm = m1 + m2;
        const vu3 = (m1 - m2) / mm * u1 + (2 * m2) / mm * u3;
        const vu1 = (m2 - m1) / mm * u3 + (2 * m1) / mm * u1;
        a.x = a.x + a.vx * time;
        a.y = a.y + a.vy * time;
        b.x = b.x + b.vx * time;
        b.y = b.y + b.vy * time;
        b.vx = x * vu1 - y * u4;
        b.vy = y * vu1 + x * u4;
        a.vx = x * vu3 - y * u2;
        a.vy = y * vu3 + x * u2;
        a.x = a.x - a.vx * time;
        a.y = a.y - a.vy * time;
        b.x = b.x - b.vx * time;
        b.y = b.y - b.vy * time;
    },
    doesOverlap(ball) {
        const x = this.x - ball.x;
        const y = this.y - ball.y;
        return  (this.r + ball.r) > ((x * x + y * y) ** 0.5);  
    }       
}

function canAdd(ball) {
    for (const b of balls) {
        if (ball.doesOverlap(b)) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function create(bCount) {
    lines.push(new Line(-10, 10, ctx.canvas.width + 10, 5));
    lines.push((new Line(-10, ctx.canvas.height - 2, ctx.canvas.width + 10, ctx.canvas.height - 10)).reverse());
    lines.push((new Line(10, -10, 4, ctx.canvas.height + 10)).reverse());
    lines.push(new Line(ctx.canvas.width - 3, -10, ctx.canvas.width - 10, ctx.canvas.height + 10)); 

    while (bCount--) {
        let tries = 100;
        debugger

        while (tries--) {
            const dir = Math.rand(0, Math.TAU);
            const vel = Math.rand(velMin, velMax);
            const ball = new Ball(
                Math.rand(maxBallSize + 10, canvas.width - maxBallSize - 10), 
                Math.rand(maxBallSize + 10, canvas.height - maxBallSize - 10),
                Math.cos(dir) * vel,
                Math.sin(dir) * vel,
                Math.rand(minBallSize, maxBallSize),
            )

            if (canAdd(ball)) {
                balls.push(ball);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function resolveCollisions() {
    var minTime = 0, minObj, minBall, resolving = true, idx = 0, idx1, after = 0, e = 0;
        
    while (resolving && e++ < maxResolutionCycles) { // too main ball may create very lone resolution cycle. e limits this
        resolving = false;
        minObj = undefined;
        minBall = undefined;
        minTime = 1;
        idx = 0;

        for(const b of balls) {
            idx1 = idx + 1;
            while (idx1 < balls.length) {
                const b1 = balls[idx1++];
                const time = b.interceptBallTime(b1, after);

                if (time !== undefined) {
                    if (time <= minTime) {
                         minTime = time;
                        minObj = b1;
                        minBall = b;
                        resolving = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (const l of lines) {
                 const time = b.interceptLineTime(l, after);
                if (time !== undefined) {
                    if (time <= minTime) {
                        minTime = time;
                        minObj = l;
                        minBall = b;
                        resolving = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            idx++;
        }

        if (resolving) {
            if (minObj instanceof Ball) {
                minBall.collide(minObj, minTime);
            } else {
                minBall.collideLine(minObj, minTime);
            }

            after = minTime;
        }
    }
}

function mainLoop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    resolveCollisions();

    for (const b of balls) {
        b.update()
    }

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();

    for (const b of balls) {
        b.draw()
    }

    for (const l of lines) {
        l.draw()
    }

    ctx.stroke();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}    

function addBall() {
    numBalls++;
    ballCount.innerHTML = numBalls;
    create(1);
}

mainLoop();
```

```css
#canvas {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 550px
}

#myConsole {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <title>Bouncy Balls</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="addBall()">Add Ball</button><br>
        <div>Ball Count: <span id="ball-count">0</span></div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <p id="myConsole">&gt;&nbsp;<span id="myMessage"></span></p>

        <script src="app2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Please read the post again, @Barmar. Thank you.